# submit a form with mooTools, and have the forms inline onsubmit event fire...help

Tags: javascript, events, forms, mootools, submit

Im writing a class that replaces all `input type="button"` and `input type="submit"` in the document with a custom button, that is actually a span stuffed inside of an anchor tag, i've got everything written, and it all works, except the inline `onsubmit` event is not being fired when the form is submitted with a javascript.

Actually, even writing a static anchor tag

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.FORMNAME.submit();">Submit</a>
```

will not fire the inline `onsubmit` event for the form, but `<input type="submit" />` will fire the event...anyways there has to be a way to fire this onsubmit event with javascript.

Heres a snippet of what im working with:

```
click: function() {

    //get parent form
    var thisForm = this.getParent('form');

    //fire onsubmit event
    thisForm.fireEvent('submit'); //this doesnt work!

    //submit form...the event isn't fired here either!
    thisForm.submit();

}
```

anybody have any ideas? this class needs to need no configuration and there are some older sites using our cms system that we want to plug this into, and there are quite a few inline submit events on the forms we need to account for

Thanks

UPDATE,

I took the suggestion and came up with this:

```
if(this.getParent().onsubmit()) {
    this.getParent().submit();
}
```

works perfectly for evaluating the forms onsubmit event and submitting the form based on its output, but what if the function doesn't exist at all? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firing `submit` on a form doesn't trigger it's inline `onSubmit`, this is default javascript behaviour (found this: http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4QS3RL/)

You can try calling `onsubmit` yourself though, this works for me:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.3.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            window.addEvent('domready', function(e) {
               $$('span.submit').each(function(el) {
                  el.addEvent('click', function(e) {
                    this.getParent().onsubmit();
                  });
               });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" onsubmit="alert('hi');" class="form">
            <input type="text" value="test" />
            <span class="submit">Submit the form</span>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that works...but not completely, what about evaluating `onsubmit()`...thats easy enough, but what about if there's no `onsubmit()` at all, how do I then not evaluate it.

Comment: You just have to check if the `onsubmit` attribute is defined and not empty, if true, then call it as a method.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this code instead as it will check to see if the onsubmit event has been attached as an event listener rather than being a hard encoded attribute. If the event was attached as a listener the [form element].onsubmit() part won't work.

```
    function myOnSubmit(formId){
        var f = document.getElementById(formId);
        if(document.createEvent){
            var e = document.createEvent('Event');
            e.initEvent('submit',true,false);
            f.dispatchEvent(e);
        } elseif(document.createEventObject){
            var e = document.createEventObject('Event');
            e.button = 1;
            f.fireEvent('onsubmit',e);
        } elseif(typeof(f.onsubmit) == 'function'){
            f.onsubmit();
        }
    }
```